# In ggplot2, unable to change point colors whose color I want to vary

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Here is what my current output looks like. Right now, the points are different shades of blue.

[image]

1. How can I make the points different shades of another color, e.g., purple.
2. How can I choose the colors for the points from colors in a colorblind-friendly palette?

When I have tried to do it, I get an error such as this one: "discrete value supplied to continuous scale."

I have looked at stackoverflow solutions for my problem, but did not see what that enabled me to solve it. If one exists, I would appreciate it if you can share its link.

**My dput**

```
structure(list(Player = c("Al Jackson", "Dwight Gooden", "Scott Erickson", 
"Wally Whitehurst", "Larry Miller", "Jack Hamilton", "Brian Bohanon", 
"Greg Harris", "Julio Valera", "Mark Bomback", "Frank Viola", 
"Mark Clark", "Rafael Montero", "Jay Hook", "John Pacella", "Dave Roberts", 
"Juan Berenguer", "Bill Hepler", "Mike Bruhert", "Ed Lynch", 
"Brian Bannister", "Jack Fisher", "Rob Gardner", "Dillon Gee", 
"Mickey Lolich", "Tug McGraw", "John Candelaria", "Rich Hill", 
"Mike Hampton", "Tom Seaver", "Octavio Dotel", "Jason Isringhausen", 
"Jackson Todd", "Nelson Figueroa", "Galen Cisco"), QS = c(73, 
209, 1, 8, 1, 7, 9, 5, 1, 10, 52, 33, 9, 24, 7, 1, 4, 1, 8, 48, 
2, 73, 8, 58, 18, 12, 1, 2, 18, 293, 7, 25, 3, 7, 30), W = c(36, 
137, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 7, 35, 19, 2, 10, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 24, 
1, 32, 2, 34, 7, 7, 1, 0, 13, 173, 5, 14, 2, 3, 12)), row.names = c(NA, 
-35L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**My code**

```
gQ <- ggplot(qs_dput, aes(x=QS, y=W, group=1)) + geom_point(aes(col=W), size=3) + geom_smooth(method="lm", col="orange", se=FALSE) 

gQ2 <- gQ + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,300), ylim=c(0,180)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 300, by = 25)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 180, by = 30)) +
  labs(title="Wins by Mets Pitchers in Their Quality Starts", x="Quality Starts", y="Wins", caption="Data from Stathead") + labs(colour = "Wins")

plot(gQ2)
```

Comment: See the documentation for `scale_color_continuous` or `scale_color_manual`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a palette designed for continuous variables. In the case of Brewer palettes, this would be a sequential (e.g., `"Blues"`) or diverging (e.g., `"PuOr"`) palette, but not a qualitative palette (e.g., `"Set1"`). You also need to pass continuous Brewer palettes to `scale_color_distiller()`, while discrete Brewer palettes are set via `scale_color_brewer()`.

Information including palette type and colorblind safety is in RColorBrewer::brewer.pal.info. So to find continuous, colorblind-safe palettes:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

brewer.pal.info[
  brewer.pal.info$colorblind & brewer.pal.info$category != "qual", 
]
#>         maxcolors category colorblind
#> BrBG           11      div       TRUE
#> PiYG           11      div       TRUE
#> PRGn           11      div       TRUE
#> PuOr           11      div       TRUE
#> RdBu           11      div       TRUE
#> RdYlBu         11      div       TRUE
#> Blues           9      seq       TRUE
#> BuGn            9      seq       TRUE
#> BuPu            9      seq       TRUE
#> GnBu            9      seq       TRUE
#> Greens          9      seq       TRUE
#> Greys           9      seq       TRUE
#> Oranges         9      seq       TRUE
#> OrRd            9      seq       TRUE
#> PuBu            9      seq       TRUE
#> PuBuGn          9      seq       TRUE
#> PuRd            9      seq       TRUE
#> Purples         9      seq       TRUE
#> RdPu            9      seq       TRUE
#> Reds            9      seq       TRUE
#> YlGn            9      seq       TRUE
#> YlGnBu          9      seq       TRUE
#> YlOrBr          9      seq       TRUE
#> YlOrRd          9      seq       TRUE
```

"Purples" is continuous and colorblind-safe, so let's try that:

```
gQ <- ggplot(qs_dput, aes(x=QS, y=W, group=1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=W), size=3) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", col="orange", se=FALSE)

gQ2 <- gQ + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,300), ylim=c(0,180)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 300, by = 25)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 180, by = 30)) +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "Purples", direction = 1) +
  labs(
    title="Wins by Mets Pitchers in Their Quality Starts", 
    x="Quality Starts", 
    y="Wins", 
    caption="Data from Stathead",
    colour = "Wins"
  )

gQ2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

[image]

The {colorBlindness} package is also a good resource. Its [introductory vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorBlindness/vignettes/colorBlindness.html) lists other colorblind-safe palettes.

Answer (score 0):

I used a colorblind-friendly palette with black from this link: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/. You can change the colors and number of colors in the cbbpalette code below. You can use this code:

```
cbbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

gQ <- ggplot(qs_dput, aes(x=QS, y=W, group=1)) + geom_point(aes(col=W), size=3) + geom_smooth(method="lm", col="orange", se=FALSE) +   scale_color_gradientn(colours = cbbPalette)


gQ2 <- gQ + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,300), ylim=c(0,180)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 300, by = 25)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 180, by = 30)) +
      labs(title="Wins by Mets Pitchers in Their Quality Starts", x="Quality Starts", y="Wins", caption="Data from Stathead") + labs(colour = "Wins")
    
plot(gQ2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What makes you say that palette is colorblind-safe? With simulated protanopia or deuteranopia the lowest (orange) and highest (red) values are very hard to distinguish, as are the greens vs purples and different shades of blue. See colorblind simulation [here](https://davidmathlogic.com/colorblind/#%23000000-%23E69F00-%2356B4E9-%23009E73-%23F0E442-%230072B2-%23D55E00-%23CC79A7).

Comment: @zephryl I used this link which gives a colorblind-safe palette: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/

Comment: fair enough, thank you. it doesn't look great to my eye, but [looks to have been developed by people who know much more about it than I do](https://jfly.uni-koeln.de/color/). I might suggest including the link you provided in your answer.

Comment: I just added the link where I got the colorblind-safe palette from.